# Devise authenticating with username instead of email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm new to Devise and have it working fine by using an email address as the authentication key.  However, I have a use case which requires a username instead and I can't seem to get it working.

I've added a string column, "username" to the users table, changed the fields from :email to :username in the sign-in form, and have changed the authentication key in devise.rb to :username yet when I go to sign in I'm met with this prompt: "Please enter an email address".

What am I doing wrong?

```
**new.html.erb**

  <div><%= f.label :username %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :username %></div>

**User.rb**
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :encryptable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :authentication_keys => [:username]

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :username
  # attr_accessible :title, :body
end

**devise.rb**
 config.authentication_keys = [ :username ]
```

Comment: did you restart your rails app?

Comment: Yes, restarted rails server also pulled out what you mentioned.  No joy.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

In your config/initializers/devise.rb uncomment `config.authentication_keys = [ :email]` and change it to `config.authentication_keys = [ :username ]`

**Update:**
 Your form's incorrect.
Change `f.email_field` to `f.text_field`

Comment: That's how I have it set. config.authentication_keys = [ :username ]

Comment: Holy cow that was stupid.  Thanks for pointing it out to me. Guess I shouldn't play with stuff when I'm tired.

Comment: When you are using `scoped_views`, you can move the authentication keys to model level using ````devise authentication_keys => [:email]````

Answer (score 2):

- First of all, make sure to run the migrations.

`bundle exec rake db:migrate`

- Generate the views for Devise, otherwise Devise will use the defaults.

`rails generate devise:views`

- Change the Devise/views as you want (replacing email field to username field)
- Restart the webserver

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Adding to rb512 answer

When you set `config.authentication_keys` to `[:username]` it's also convenient to set

- `config.case_insensitive_keys = [:username]`
- `config.strip_whitespace_keys = [:username]`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31371317)

Answer (score -1):

i don't know how much has changed since ~2012 but this i what i had to do on **Rails 7** in 2022 when changing authentication from email to internal_id.

1. config.authentication_keys = [:internal_id] (in devise.rb)
2. add internal_id to user via migration
3. update the user model to look like this:

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :rememberable, authentication_keys: [:internal_id]

validates :internal_id, presence: true, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
```

for 3. it is important to remove the :validatable, :recoverable and :registerable modules from devise.

for more information check:

- https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address
- https://github.com/heartcombo/devise (top of the README shows what the different modules are doing)