# Devise: Replacing 'email' not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I've replaced email with accountnumber throughout every single document using the sublime replace in all files feature.

I've reset and re-migrated the DB, however, when registering I still get the following error:

```
undefined method `email' for #<Account:0x415b690>
```

and then the following parameters

```
    {"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"2qqA7dx99hx+VqkZGDmySNJd+2Fzxuanegy1ysrpD30=",
 "account"=>{"accountnumber"=>"1307",
 "password"=>"[FILTERED]",
 "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"},
 "commit"=>"Sign up"}
```

Has anyone had this difficulty before? Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Devise: Replace 'email' with alternative for sign in](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24746870/devise-replace-email-with-alternative-for-sign-in)

Answer (score 0):

Devise has its build in dependency on email.
It uses it as its main identifier for authentication. 
To be able to use anything else as the identifier reference this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10866667/devise-authenticating-with-username-instead-of-email)