# Devise: Replace 'email' with alternative for sign in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I tried to replace `email` with `accountnumber` throughout my whole application using Sublime's "replace in all files" feature.

I've reset and re-migrated the DB, however, when registering I still get the following error:

```
undefined method `email' for #<Account:0x415b690>
```

and then the following parameters

```
    {"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"2qqA7dx99hx+VqkZGDmySNJd+2Fzxuanegy1ysrpD30=",
 "account"=>{"accountnumber"=>"1307",
 "password"=>"[FILTERED]",
 "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"},
 "commit"=>"Sign up"}
```

Has anyone had this difficulty before?

Comment: Is this an existing app or a new app? If the latter, there's no need for search-and-replace—this should be done in your Devise config.

Comment: It's an app I created from scratch the other day, any idea where it can be changed?

Answer (score 0):

With Devise, the convention is to use 'email' for sign in. You're using a gem (Devise), so not all the code is visible in your project, and a search-and-replace to substitute 'accountnumber' for 'email' is not enough. You have to reconfigure Devise by making changes to your Account model.

Be sure to change 'email' to 'accountnumber' in the migration Devise created ('DeviseCreateUsers') and run `rake db:migrate:reset`.

Change your Account model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,  
         :authentication_keys => [:accountnumber]

  def email_required?
    false
  end

  def email_changed?
    false
  end

end
```

Make sure you've generated Devise views and changed 'email' to 'accountnumber' in the view files.

I've written a [Rails Devise Tutorial](http://railsapps.github.io/rails-devise/) that will help you understand how Devise works.