# Devise throws and error during migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am trying to use Devise in my rails app but when I get to the point to migrate my database Devise gives me this error:

```
rake db:migrate
== 20141016065244 AddDeviseToPatients: migrating ==============================
-- change_table(:patients)
   -> 0.0127s
-- add_index(:patients, :email, {:unique=>true})
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::ConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: patients.email: CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "index_patients_on_email" ON "patients" ("email")
```

I am trying to use devise in an already started project where the "User" table is called "Patient".

This is that table:

```
"Patient(id: integer, name: string, loginName: string, login: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)"
```

So what simple error am I making? :)

Here's the migration file: https://gist.github.com/macmattias/1c81717dbf218d18dc72

Answer (score 1):

The field email is missing?

You need to add a field email to your table patients.

Comment: Yes I do not have it but the migration wants to add it.

Comment: ofcourse the migration wants a email field, because the email field is the 'loginname'. there is a question about using a other field instead of email: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10866667/devise-authenticating-with-username-instead-of-email

Comment: and the error from the migration is because of add_index :patients, :email,                unique: true. You cant add an index on a field that not exists.

Comment: Earlier in the migration file it alters my table and tries to add email. I added it myself but got duplicate column name: email. I have changed in the config to loginName instead, because that is what I want but still I get the original error.