# "Unpermitted parameter: email" when submitted on Devise sign-up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have a simple Ruby on Rails app, with Devise for authentication.  I would like to have users log in using a username instead of email, and attempted to implement this as described here:
[Devise authenticating with username instead of email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10866667/devise-authenticating-with-username-instead-of-email)

The twist is that I still want each User to have an email address, and require one during sign-up.  So, I left the 'email' field on the sign-up form.

The problem is, when I fill out the sign-up form using a valid email address (or any other value for email), Devise gives an error: "Email can't be blank".

Why is the email being treated as blank, and how can I fix it?

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me) }
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) { |u| u.permit(:username, :password, :remember_me) }
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password) }
  end
end
```

User model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

View for the sign-up

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :username %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :username %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <% if @validatable %>
    <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
    <% end %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

devise.rb modified to include:

```
config.authentication_keys = [ :username ]
```

This is output in the rails server console when the form is submitted:

```
Started POST "/users" for ::1 at 2015-03-17 14:29:13 -0700
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"bc5+ffyBSr6h79aumdMpwHhp5OY69
Tk5oKyY+eIBHLCDDwPmxiMbjbE6OTIaeUPGLmS0J+QlwlGFGHki8SKsgA==", "user"=>{"email"=>
"jessa@example.com", "username"=>"Jessa", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_co
nfirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
Unpermitted parameter: email
   (0.0ms)  BEGIN
   (0.0ms)  ROLLBACK
  Rendered devise/shared/_links.html.erb (2.0ms)
  Rendered devise/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application (11.0ms)
```

I can see `Unpermitted parameter: email`, but am not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Can you please update your question to include your controller, view, and model code?

Comment: @patrick I've edited the question to include source code.  I've done very little modification after generating it.

Comment: Try adding :email to the `application_controller` for the sign_in part. But just don't include it on your sign-in form. You can leave it on your sign-up form. I think whats happening is it is trying to create the user then sign them in automatically and the email param is not permitted.

Comment: I just tried it and got an identical result as before.  I'm not even getting to the sign-in process.  The account fails to be created; no user record exists for it.

Comment: hmm, I just have set up a devise app with your parameter_sanitizer settings and everything works as expected, i used Rails 4.2.0 and devise-3.4.1. In case you want to try to find a differences i've put it [here](https://app.box.com/s/j2dh2ejb1lzn8r1chpqprz0hu5r2fkmx)

Comment: @EvgenyPetrov Thank you, that revealed the problem!  It's pretty stupid.  I had a file open in my editor with the same name, but from a throwaway project.  The code was fine, it was just in the wrong place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in question is correct, and works.  It can used as a working example of devise log-ins using a username, though there are plenty of tutorials that cover this.

The error was a stupid mistake:  a file was accidentally in the wrong place.  Thanks goes to Evgeny Petrov, who's example provided in the comments helped me to track down the discrepancy.

Answer (score 0):

Check Out this link http://jacopretorius.net/2014/03/adding-custom-fields-to-your-devise-user-model-in-rails-4.html. What you need to do is create new controller called Registration that inherits from Devise Controller. Then in your user model define a method called log_in params and pass it the values you want. This will allow you to customize views on your Log in and Sign Up pages based on your given needs. Also here is Devise's own instruction on how to do this https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address