# Rails devise username should be nil when for admin type user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have follow the device documentation [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address) to allow user sign in using their username or email address.

I want to allow user with `admin: true` only login with their email only. So from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10866667/devise-authenticating-with-username-instead-of-email) is it possible to do something like:

```
if current_user.admin?
 config.authentication_keys = [ :username ]
else
 config.authentication_keys = [ :login ] # can use username/email
end
```

or is it any better solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

This will not work as the config is done in devise.rb, which is an [initializer](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#using-initializer-files) that runs only once (when the application is loaded).

I don't see an easy way to make this work - but what would be the problem to allows anyone to use either their email or username?

Comment: I want admin can't use username to login just email